# 404 error on Laravel after uploading a file

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload some pictures on my website, it seems to work because ls -ila command returns that :

```
156635331 -rwxrwxrwx  1 sc1vjfd9614 sc1vjfd9614  139194  3 août  19:07 4CBU96b0Ec7HHD7q7wt0T6MhPiK.jpg
156635332 -rwxrwxrwx  1 sc1vjfd9614 sc1vjfd9614   67877  3 août  19:07 9LxUUR5UnwST7y1XItgdORNevyy.jpg
```

Here is the PHP code :

```
 if($posterFile = file_get_contents('https://example.com/t/p/original/'.$media['poster_path']))
    {
        file_put_contents('/home/server/website/site/public/images/covers/'.$media['poster_path'] .'' , file_get_contents('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/'.$media['poster_path']));    
    }
```

And I got a 404 error when I go to https://www.example.com/public/images/covers/d3QCvZT8DilZm7qQ5moHMJa1jeC.jpg

I already apply a chmod -R 777 on the folder

Comment: Have you tried **https://www.example.com/images/covers/d3QCvZT8DilZm7qQ5moHMJa1jeC.jpg**?? So removing the public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the URL to refer to some file on public folder, don't put the public folder, the laravel path starts from this folder.

example.com/images/covers/d3QCvZT8DilZm7qQ5moHMJa1jeC.jpg